# extJs 5 - grid multiple level grouping

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs5

I'm looking for a way to group my data by months and the months by years... two levels of grouping.
For now, I can group my data only by years...

Can anyone help me please ?

My model :

```
Ext.define('User', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [ 
// 'name', 
// 'email', 
'phone' ]});
```

My data :

```
var userStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
model: 'User',
data: [
    { year: '2015', month : 'march', phone: '555-111-1224' },
    { year: '2015', month : 'april', phone: '555-222-1234' },
    { year: '2014', month : 'march', phone: '555-222-1244' },
    { year: '2014', month : 'april', phone: '555-222-1254' }
],
groupField: 'year'});
```

The grid :

```
Ext.application({

name   : 'MyApp',

launch : function() {

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        features: [{ ftype: 'grouping' }],
        store: userStore,
        width: 250,
        height: 300,
        title: 'Application Users',
        columns: [
            {
                text: 'Phone Number',
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'phone',
                sortable: false,
                hideable: false
            }
        ]
    });
}});
```

Thx in advance !
Mayes

Comment: So you want a user to be able to expand a list of years, and then further expand a sub-list of months before seeing relevant numbers?  That sounds like you want a [TreePanel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel) rather than a grouped grid.

Comment: Yes that's it... but I want to do it using a grid panel instead of tree panel but it seems I can't do it using extJS 5

Comment: TreePanel's can have columns.  It will appear just like grid, but will have the nested groups that you require.   

Try looking at the locking tree grid example: http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/tree/locking-treegrid.html.  

You may not need the column locking feature, but otherwise, that example seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

On the store, try using the [grouper](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-grouper) config instead of the groupField.  It will give you more flexibility in how you are grouping your data.

Here's an example for your scenario:

```
var userStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    data: [
        { year: '2015', month : 'march', phone: '555-111-1224' },
        { year: '2015', month : 'april', phone: '555-222-1234' },
        { year: '2014', month : 'march', phone: '555-222-1244' },
        { year: '2014', month : 'april', phone: '555-222-1254' }
    ],    
    grouper: {
        groupFn: function(item) {
            return 'Month: ' + item.get('month') + ', Year: ' + item.get('year');
        }
    }
);
```

Please see https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/jh9 to see it in action.